# Cakephp load Appcontroller method in component

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I want to load Appcontroller method in component.

Here is my Appcontroller

```
public function date_conversion($date = "11/06/13") {
    $date_format = 'm/d/y';
    $input_date = explode('/', $date);
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($input_date[0] . '/' . $input_date[1] . '/' . $input_date[2]));
}
```

Here is my component

```
public function getWeeklyData($start_date)
{
 //AppController::date_conversion($start_date); // Not working
 $appController = ClassRegistry::init('AppController'); 
 $start_date = $appController->date_conversion($start_date);
 echo $start_date;
 exit;
 --------
 ---------
 --------
 --------
 return $final_data;
}
```

I have tried this
 `AppController::methodName()`

It's not working

Thanks

Comment: I think the idea of CakePHP components is to implement in a single place functionality that is used across multiple Controllers (to keep the code DRY). It seems to me it would be better to implement that function in a place to make it more convenient to re-use, e.g. a Component / Helper / Lib or even a Model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just plain wrong:

- Output formatting code in a controller instead of a helper ([TimeHelper::format()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/source-class-Cake.View.Helper.TimeHelper.html#340-356) doesnt work?) and view
- Using a method from AppController in a component, ouch, that really hurts, it basically inverts the idea of components.
- Business logic in the component instead of the model layer (getWeeklyData())
- You're not following any coding standard conventions
- There is even markup in the component method... You defeat the idea of separating presentation from business logic

You have seriously **absolutely** no idea what you're doing in terms of design patterns or how CakePHP works. Why are you using a framework at all if you don't use it properly in any way. The code tells me that you really have no idea why there are different things like controllers, models or components and what they are.

I recommend you to start over and learn the basics of [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) frameworks and design patterns before trying to implement an application. If the whole app code looks like your pasted code it's just unmaintainable spaghetti code at the end of the day. Start reading here https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html and do the blog tutorial as well. There is simply to much wrong with this code and your understanding of it, it's to exhaustive to explain all of it here in full length.

Answer (score -1):

If you have AppController class like this:-

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public function callApp(){
        return "This is App Controller and a non-static method";
    }

    public static function staticApp(){
        return "This is a static method";
    }
}
```

Then you can call it in Component like this:-

```
<?php
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
class FooComponent extends Component{
    public function Foo(){
        // For non static method
        $appController = ClassRegistry::init('AppController');  // Get 
reference of AppController
        echo $appController->callApp();

        echo "<br>";
        // For static method
        echo AppController::staticApp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, It's not working says fatal error Fatal error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object

Comment: It would be better to help if you edit your question and share your code as well. @SuneelKumar

Comment: This code is horribly wrong in so many aspects... I listed a few of them in my answer.